# Difference between featureid and featurenumber

Tags: qgis, atlas-generator

I have created an Atlas and I want to show the page number of each Atlas page. For that, I can create a label and either use

`[% @atlas_featureid %]` or `[% @atlas_featurenumber %]`

But what is the difference between the two? Which one is better to use?

Comment: look at the official documentation https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html for show page number you can use for example `[%'Page '||@atlas_featurenumber || '/' || @atlas_totalfeatures%]`

Comment: @FranRaga - You should post your comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

look at the official [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html) and for show page number you can use for example:

```
[%'Page '||@atlas_featurenumber || '/' || @atlas_totalfeatures%]
```